# group values in set of 5 and then return the first value from each group

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a long list of values of a stock in minute format. The column C shows the open values(per minute) and column F shows the corresponding close values

Now I want to covert this data into 5 min format from 1 minute. this mean for column C I want first value to be displaced for a group of 5 (i.e c1 from C1:C5, then c6 from C6:C10, then C11 from C11:C15) and in the column F I want the last value of the group. see below the highlighted i need

(i.e F5 from F1:F5, then F10 from F6:F10 then F15 from F11:F15).

I don't know how to use OFFSET/ INDEX/MATCH in combination to achieve these results. later on i will also like to convert this to 10 min/30min/60min format

Comment: So what have you tried to figure out using OFFSET or INDEX/MATCH? What results are you getting that are incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your help.. I was looking for a simple solution and thankfully combination of INDEX and OFFSET help to resolve this. I used the following formula:

=INDEX(OFFSET(A$1,(ROW(A1)-1)*2,0,2),2,0)

in the above formula helped to convert the list into group of 2 ( or any other group based on the requirement and hence 2 can be changed to 5, 10 etc.) and Index helped to locate the last value of the group. worked pretty well for me.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I see you tagged worksheet-function so try the vba code below.

You can change the ipWorksheet and opWorksheet variables to worksheets in your excel.
Also if you want to change rowOn to another number depending on where you want to start getting your data from

```
Sub Extract_Nth_rows()
'
' Extract_Nth_rows
'

    Dim rowOn, rowTotal, rowJump As Integer
    Dim ipWorksheet, opWorksheet As String

    ipWorksheet = "Sheet1"                              ' CHANGE THIS to the name of your Data sheet
    opWorksheet = "Sheet2"                              ' CHANGE THIS to the name of the sheet to put the data

    rowOn = 1                                           ' This will start on Row 1 of Sheet1
    rowTotal = Sheets(ipWorksheet).UsedRange.Rows.Count ' Count number of Rows


    Sheets(opWorksheet).Cells.Clear                     ' Clear all rows

    While rowOn < rowTotal
        Sheets(ipWorksheet).Select
        Rows(rowOn * 5 & ":" & rowOn * 5).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets(opWorksheet).Select
        Range("A" & rowOn).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        rowOn = rowOn + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this. It has Index and Group commands that should achieve what you want.

I've built a solution for a similar which you can view or download - its: "Power Query demo - Unpivoting pairs of rows into two columns.xlsx" in my One Drive:

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=4FA287BBC10EC562%21398

First I add an Index column (sequential row number), then apply a Number.Mod function to group every 2 rows.  For you scenario just change that to 5 rows.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/number-mod-HA104110103.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA104122363

You might alternatively want to group by the time values (rather than assuming there will always be 5 rows) - Power Query has functions to help this e.g. Time.Minute

http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/time-minute-HA104110495.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA104122363

After calculating your grouping value as a new column, then use that with the Group command to summarize your data:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/group-rows-in-a-table-HA103993875.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA103993930